# Data Table Solution To Name Search

Tags: r, data.table, grepl

```
NAMES = data.table(names1 = c("John","mary","james","Mark","abi"), 
                   list1 = c("bam","cameron","tony","lucas","tim"))
NAMES_SUBSET = NAMES[names1 %like% "ma" | list1 %like% "am"]
```

I have a data.table 'NAMES' that contains various column names; all the columns contains a list of names that may or may not have proper capitalization, for example some first letters are uppercase but some are not.

I want to create 'NAMES_SUBSET' that ONLY contains the rows in 'NAMES' that contain "ma" or "Ma" or "am" or "Am" in any of the columns.

My current attempt is not a good solution, because I do not know how to search the data.table for all rows but only one columns at a time and I do not know how to make it case insensitive. Thank you

My hopeful output is:

```
names1  list1
John    bam
mary    cameron
james   tony
Mark    lucas
```

Comment: Maybe something like `NAMES[apply(NAMES, 1, function(x) any(grepl("am|ma", tolower(x))))]`?

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
desired_rows <- NAMES[, lapply(.SD, function(x) grepl("ma|am", x, ignore.case = TRUE))] 
NAMES_SUBSET <- NAMES[rowSums(desired_rows) > 0]
```

The first line uses `.SD` to look through all the columns, and `grepl()` to search for matches to either of your patterns, with the `ignore.case = TRUE` argument.

The second line uses that to filter your original dataset.

Output:

```
> NAMES_SUBSET
   names1   list1
1:   John     bam
2:   mary cameron
3:  james    tony
4:   Mark   lucas
```

If you're doing this a lot, you can write it as a function like this:

```
search_all_dtcols <- function(dataset, pattern) {
  dt <- dataset[, lapply(.SD, function(x) grepl(pattern, x, ignore.case = TRUE))] 
  dataset[rowSums(dt) > 0]
}
```

Output:

```
> search_all_dtcols(NAMES, "ma|am")
   names1   list1
1:   John     bam
2:   mary cameron
3:  james    tony
4:   Mark   lucas
```